# Differential of an element of the group of rigid motions

Tags: differential-geometry

Please why is the differential of an element of the group of rigid motions of $ R^{n}$  $ g= t \circ r $ where t is a translation and r is a rotation,  $$ Dg(p,n)= r , \forall (p,n) \in {R}^{3} \times S^{2} $$

Comment: Can you please show you a little more context to this problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to calculate the differential the way i know it, but i got nothing. I'm new to this so i'm still having problems with such examples.;